# Launching a text file from a .jar file (File path?)

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar

I'm trying to launch a text file from a .jar file using Desktop.getDesktop().open(file)

```
String fileName = "file.txt";

URL url = getClass().getResource(fileName);
File fileToRead = new File(url.toURI());
Desktop.getDesktop().open(fileToRead);
```

I omitted the try-catch blocks for simplicity.
It is able to open my file when run from eclipse. But once I export to a .jar file, I get a NullPointerException in ***File fileToRead = new File(url.toURI());***

Comment: Where is the "file.txt" saved?

Comment: you can't "launch a text file", that's not an executable. Did you check whether or not the file is still found? add a print statement with the url you're using, and check your drive whether the file does exist

Comment: Could you correct your example? Currently we don't know what is `file` (I suspect you wanted `fileName` there)

Comment: Even if you solve your NPE problem (which is caused by not matching structure of jar or relative path you used), you can't simply run file from archive like jar. You can think that you are able to do so in your OS with simple double-click, but it is possible only because file is first extracted to some temporary directory like in Windows 7 `c:/Users/USER_NAME/AppData/Local/Temp/ARCHIVE_NAME/FILE_ENTRY` and then this extracted file is being executed.

Comment: Yea I meant fileName in the second line. file.txt is in the same folder as the package that runs the above code. When run from eclipse the file gets launched. Are you saying that it would not open from a .jar file?

Answer (score 0):

When you package a class in a .jar file, it usually makes it nested one level deeper.

Therefore, you can try changing the first line to:

```
String filename = "../file.txt";
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the JavaDoc of [`Class.getResource(String)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getResource-java.lang.String-):

> an absolute resource name is constructed from the given resource name using this algorithm:
>
> If the name begins with a '/', then the absolute name of the resource is the portion of the name following the '/'.
>   Otherwise, the absolute name is of the following form:
>   `modified_package_name/name`
>   Where the `modified_package_name` is the package name of this object with '/' substituted for '.'.
>
> Parameters:
>
> name - name of the desired resource
>
> Returns:
>   A URL object or **null** if no resource with this name is found

Your resource was not found, hence NullPointerException. Specify the path within the JAR as described by the JavaDoc (absolute path starting with '/' or relative to the class of `this`, the object where you are calling `getClass().getResource(fileName)`) and you should get it.